# PHP Error - Failed To Open Stream - No Expertise with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stream

I picked up a site from another designer and it's all php, which I only know a tiny bit of from working with wordpress.

Here's my issue, I click on a link that is suppose to open up a page of photos on the site, but instead of getting the page: www.willowbeach.com/our-cottages-photos.php
[image]
I get this:

Warning: `require(/home/willowbe/public_html/db/db_class.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnaweb19a/b512/nf.burlingtonchocolatet/public_html/willowbeach/db/application_top.php on line 14 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/willowbe/public_html/db/db_class.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnaweb19a/b512/nf.burlingtonchocolatet/public_html/willowbeach/db/application_top.php on line 14`

I know it has to do with the fact that the path is a local system one and not the web directory path. But I have no clue where to go to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error carefully, it tells you exactly where to go and what PHP was trying to do:

PHP was attempting to run

```
require(/home/willowbe/public_html/db/db_class.inc.php)
```

Which is located at

`/hermes/bosnaweb19a/b512/nf.burlingtonchocolatet/public_html/willowbeach/db/application_top.php`

on line 14.

It could not locate the file there, thus the error.

Now, putting this website into a complex directory tree like `/hermes/bosnaweb19a/b512/nf.burlingtonchocolatet/public_html/willowbeach` seems unecessarily complex to me, but I'm sure you had reasons to put it there.

Starting at `application_top.php` on line 14, you have to find all full path references to `/home/willowbe/public_html/` and replace them with `/hermes/bosnaweb19a/b512/nf.burlingtonchocolatet/public_html/willowbeach/` so the files are found by php.

Comment: Okay so when I pull up application_top.php I get this:  

# Session 

 session_start();

 require('config.php');
# DB Connection
 require(DIR_FUNCTION.'db_class.inc.php');
 $db = new db_mysql(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
 $db->connect();
 $db->select_db();

require(DIR_FUNCTION.'db_class.inc.php'); is the 14th line

Comment: So you need to find where `DIR_FUNCTION` is defined and point it to the right place....